# Monk flurry and haste, which bab?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monk

I am playing a monk and we have a spell caster in the group who casts haste.

Haste

> When making a full attack action, a hasted creature may make one extra attack with one natural or manufactured weapon. The attack is made using the ***creature's full base attack bonus***, plus any modifiers appropriate to the situation. (This effect is not cumulative with similar effects, such as that provided by a speed weapon, nor does it actually grant an extra action, so you can't use it to cast a second spell or otherwise take an extra action in the round.)

My question is, for the monk what value is used? Is it 3/4 bab progression, or the flurry full bab -2 progression?

Also, this value should be the same for the monk ki ability to gain an extra attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The monk uses whichever he's using.

If the monk is both *hasted* and using Flurry of Blows, he adds an additional attack in his Flurry at the highest BAB in that Flurry.  If, for some reason, he's not using Flurry of Blows (maybe he's using a non-monk weapon?), he adds an additional attack at the BAB in that full attack.

Comment: I was thinking of a single value, but you are right, it makes more sense for it to be conditional like that

Comment: Yeah, the extra attack "at the highest base attack bonus" is pretty easy to calculate: just repeat your best attack in that full attack before the rest of your iterative attacks.

Comment: Originally I was wondering if I was able to gain +2 on the extra attack because it would not gain the -2 for basically 2 weapon fighting, but that applies to all attacks made in the round

Comment: @Fering right. You could avoid the -2 by not using flurry,  but that doesn't help a "chained" monk since he drops BAB for that. Have you looked at the Unchained Monk instead?

Comment: My Monk is a zen archer so currently I cant use unchained