# Monk flurry and deadly aim, class bab or flurry bab?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monk

So last night it occurred to me that I might have been using [deadly aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat) incorrectly for the last 2 levels. I just became a 6th level monk (zen archer) and as their bab is a 3/4 progression I just got my 4th bab. So when using deadly aim this means I now take a -2 on my attack rolls but gain 4 on damage.

However, since [flurry of blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) uses my level in place of bab, does that means I should have been having that instead of my bab?

I am pretty sure the answer is going to be the same as [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/81244/23058), but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) can use his [flurry of blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) base attack bonus to determine the feat [Deadly Aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat)'s benefit

The [*Pathfinder Core Rulebook* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm) includes this [exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o72):

> **How does a monk's improved BAB when flurrying interact with feats like Power Attack and Combat Expertise, which have different effects depending on your BAB?**
>   The monk uses his improved flurrying BAB to determine the effect of those feats.

As the feat [Deadly Aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat) is awfully close to the feat [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final) except for ranged weapons, the same should apply here for a [monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) with the archetype [zen archer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/zen-archer). Also, creative director James Jacobs—independent of the FAQ—pretty much confirms this reading in [2012](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=462?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#23054).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the description of Flurry of Blows:

> For the purpose of these attacks, the monk's base attack bonus from his monk class levels is equal to his monk level. For all other purposes, such as qualifying for a feat or a prestige class, the monk uses his normal base attack bonus.

It seems pretty clear that as a lvl4 Monk you have a -2/+4 Deadly Aim during your flurries, but only during them. However you couldn't for example have selected this feat at level 1, even if you planned to use it only during flurries.

Comment: I must have selected it somewhere else then and just forgotten